# Can't set breakpoint in PHPStorm

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

Everything works fine except template files. If there are some HTML in the code breakpoints just don't add.

How do I debug PHP code in template files?

I have PHPStorm 9.0 and Xdebug 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line of code execution, a template engine is called from your controller or framework.  That would be where you would set a breakpoint; then use **step into...** to see how your template file is being handled by the template engine itself.  This is a tedious process, but depending on the framework you're using, may be your only alternative.

Having said that, I would actually recommend separating concerns by executing all PHP code in your controllers or source files; and then passing those values on to the template as simple variables or code snippets for rendering.  This follows a similar convention to "dependency injection" and will make your template files easier to compose and troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you, now I have to find out where a template is called from my framework, I guess this is a separate question. However, to solve my problems with variables in templates I managed to use good old `var_dump`

Comment: Along with `print_r` and `echo`, `var_dump` still has a place in the world of troubleshooting!  I would, however, strongly recommend that you delve into debugging with Xdebug or Zend Debugger.  As long as you're using phpStorm, it's very easy!

Comment: And don't forget file_put_contents for a good way to build a text file with of variables through out a process.